# TCSH error in foreach loop: files.list: Command not found

Tags: linux, foreach, tcsh

I am trying to pass a user-input variable (a file name) into a foreach loop in tcsh.  The user entered variable is, for example, "files.list" (saved in the same folder as the Shell Script is saved, and is being run from).

Here is my code:

```
 #! /usr/bin/tcsh -f 

echo please enter files list 

set x = $<

foreach i ('$x')    
echo $i     
end
```

What I want is for each of the words in "files.list" to be output to the screen.  Files.list contains 5 lines, each with a file name.

```
myScript22.sh
Mad45.sh
Number32.sh
killBill.sh
gotMilk.sh
bugslife.sh
```

I get an error - "foreach: Words not parenthesized."

Could it be that `'cat $x'` isn't calling the x variable correctly?  If so, how do I get the file set up so it's contents can be looped thru?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you considered using bash instead?

Comment: thanks @melpomene, I am limited to tcsh at work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really really really really have to use [tcsh](/questions/tagged/tcsh), then the following is the propper way to do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/tcsh -f
echo please enter files list
set x = $<

foreach line (" `cat $x` ")
   echo "$line"
end
```

It is important to see that the `cat` command is between <double-quotes>. The difference is that otherwise, the `foreach` statement will read word-by-word, while the double-quoted version will read line-by-line. The logic of this is ... questionable.  Also, I quoted the variable `line` in the `echo` statement, because it will actually complain when it hits an empty line.

In [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), you would just do the following nice thing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "Please enter files list"
file=""
while [[ ! -e $file ]]; do read -r file; done

while read -r line; do
  echo "$line"
done < "$file"
```

Very important reads:

- [CSH PROGRAMMING CONSIDERED HARMFUL](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/)
- [Top Ten Reasons not to use the C shell](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/CshTop10.txt)

Answer (score 0):

For reference purposes, I was missing the `cat` command, before the $x.

So the code should read:

```
 #! /usr/bin/tcsh -f 

echo please enter files list 

set x = $<

foreach i ('cat $x')    
echo $i     
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two mistakes in your tcsh script:

1. Missing cat command in front of the filename in your foreach condition.
2. Use of straight single quotes(' ') instead of backquotes (``) in your foreach condition.

The following script should work for you.

```
#!/usr/bin/tcsh -f

echo please enter files list 

set x = $<

foreach i(`cat $x`)
  echo $i
end
```